# Higgs Boson of particle physics

Tags: experimental-physics, standard-model, antimatter, higgs

can the higgs particle interact with himself as it is the antiparticle of himself?

as we know that the every particle is the excitation of their respective fields i.e higgs of higgs field so what about the antiparticle?

Comment: The Higgs boson does interact with itself; however, this has nothing to do with it being its own antiparticle.  (To clarify, the physical Higgs boson is indeed its own antiparticle.)

Comment: Feynman diagrams for Higgs self-interaction can for example be found [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1209.6213.pdf) (in e.g. equation 97).

Comment: Trying to understand where your question is coming from, you might be thinking about how a *charged* particle can annihilate its antiparticle.  In the case of electric charge, this annihilation will produce a photon.  But there are also other types of forces/ charges -- the weak force and the strong force.  In particular, the Higgs is 'charged' under the weak force, and because of this, the Higgs can annihilate its antiparticle (i.e., itself) and produce a Z boson.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the Higgs Boson gain mass itself?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/30732/)

Answer (score 0):

Its antiparticle is itself, like photon is anti-photon.

Antiparticle isn't a de-excitation of a field (well... maybe a little in the Dirac sea interpretation, but it's a not a good interpretation at all...).

Yes, the Higgs boson self-interacts with itself. It can interact splitting a boson into two (or merging two into one), splitting in three (or colliding with other, or merging three into one), and the combinations that arise from that (because quantum fields "do what they want", "have free will", "are like fairies but with well defined tastes").

For really understanding this, read peskin-schroeder "an introduction to Quantum Field Theory".

Comment: could you please complete the answers of both the questions.

Comment: What is the second question?

Comment: as we know that the every particle is the excitation of their respective fields i.e higgs of higgs field so what about the antiparticle, are they are the de-excitation of the the fields?

Comment: Antiparticle isn't a de-excitation of a field (well... maybe a little in the Dirac sea interpretation, but it's a not a good interpretation at all...). Yes, the Higgs boson self-interacts with itself. It can interact spliting a boson into two (or merging two into one), spliting in three (or colliding with other, or merging three into one), and the combinations that arise from that (because quantum fields "do what they want", "have free will", "are like fairies but with well defined tastes"). For really understanding this, read peskin-schroeder "an introduction to Quantum Field Theory".

Comment: What is the difference between the Haevy(H) and light higgs(h) and which one of them had been discovered in the in 2012 at CERN.

Comment: Where you have readen about Heavy and light higgs? If I know from where is that terminology I could know how to answer you.

Comment: some time we denote the higgs by "H" and some time by "h" why?

Comment: Where? If you could point a book, wiki page, or .pdf/.ppt/some kind of note maybe I could know about what you are talking, it apears to be related to some kind of notation...

Comment: please check the slide No. 4 of the link below
https://indico.cern.ch/event/618261/contributions/2494974/attachments/1424887/2185410/HBSM_hh_status_09_03.pdf

Comment: I can't enter to that presentation. If it's something like this: "http://www.lnf.infn.it/kloe/Lectures/kilian.pdf", then the answer is, in that kind of model the higgs is the little higgs, but that's beyond standard model (bsm). Today we don't have any evidence pointing conclusively to one bsm theory or another.

Comment: the anwser is that the H is a supersymmetric higgs which not yet discovered and other one is SM higgs boson.