# How does the Higgs boson get its mass?

Tags: particle-physics, mass, standard-model, higgs, bosons

I understand that Higgs boson gives other particles mass. But how does it get its own mass? Does it interact with another field?

Comment: It interacts with itself!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does the Higgs Boson gain mass itself?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/30732/)